# Filtering issue - showing no posts

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have created a filtering system that filters through different post types. I want to display 'no posts' if no posts are displayed when selected. However at the moment, it is displaying on every filter. I have created the following codepen:

https://codepen.io/scottYg55/pen/OexpgR

This script works, however not on click:-

```
var allHidden = $('.tile').filter(':visible').length === 0;

if($('.tile:visible').length===0){
  $('.hideme').show();
}
else{
  $('.hideme').hide();
}
```

Full click function

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var allHidden = $('.tile').filter(':visible').length === 0;
    var selectedClass = "";
    $(".blogfilter a").on('click', function(){
    $(".blogfilter a").removeClass("filter-selected");
    $(".tiles .tile").addClass("two-tile");
    $(this).addClass("filter-selected");    
    selectedClass = $(this).attr("data-rel"); 
    $("#blog-posts").fadeTo(100, 0.1);  
    $("#blog-posts .tile").not("."+selectedClass).fadeOut().removeClass('scale-anm');   

    setTimeout(function() {
        $("."+selectedClass).fadeIn().addClass('scale-anm');
            $("#blog-posts").fadeTo(300, 1);    
        }, 300);    
    });
});
```

Comment: Why not `var allHidden = $('.tile:visible').length===0; $('.hideme').toggle(allHidden)`

Comment: Where to call this in the click function?

Comment: What click function. You have not posted any click function here. Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56787543/edit) then `[<>]` and produce a [mcve] here at SO

Comment: I have added click function, please see the entire function on https://codepen.io/scottYg55/pen/OexpgR

Comment: Currently `var allHidden = $('.tile').filter(':visible').length === 0;` is ONLY executing when the page loads. You need to copy `var allHidden = $('.tile:visible').length===0; $('.hideme').toggle(allHidden)` to for example just before the timeout

Comment: Yes this has been tried, but still no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="hideme" style="display:none;">No posts</div>
```

And Script is

```
jQuery(function ($) {


    var selectedClass = "";
    $(".blogfilter a").on('click', function(){
        var datarel = $(this).data("rel");
        var hasclass = $( ".tiles .tile" ).hasClass( datarel );

        (hasclass === false) ? $(".hideme").css("display","block") :  $(".hideme").css("display","none");               


        $(".blogfilter a").removeClass("filter-selected");
        $(".tiles .tile").addClass("two-tile");
        $(this).addClass("filter-selected");    
        selectedClass = $(this).attr("data-rel"); 
        $("#blog-posts").fadeTo(100, 0.1);  
        $("#blog-posts .tile").not("."+selectedClass).fadeOut().removeClass('scale-anm');       
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("."+selectedClass).fadeIn().addClass('scale-anm');
            $("#blog-posts").fadeTo(300, 1);    
        }, 300); 


    });
});
```

Comment: Wow, thats it!! Thank you very much Vinee!

Comment: it means alot to me :)